# Run Access on low priority mode from start up

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to run my Access DB on low priority mode automaticly as soon as it starts up... (Access 2016)
a batch file with this command does not work

```
start /low c:*accdb paht*
```

Any help is welcome thanks!

Comment: I guess you can do as described [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Program-Start-at-High-Priority-%28Windows%29), replacing `/high` with `/low`.

Comment: I just did what it says on that website but its still in an normal condition and does not work as it shold any other idesa?

Comment: No. And I think Windows does this automatically; programs in the back get lower priority than that in front.

Comment: Jeah it does but still I want it to be low pryority just to make shure.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way via Powershell

```
*Access db path*
Get-WmiObject Win32_process -filter 'name = "MSACCESS.EXE"' | foreach-object {$_.SetPriority(16384)}
```

Hope this helps someone :D